# TPL Dataflow Consumer to Process Multiple Items at a time

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a requirement to iterate through a large list and for each item call a web service to get some data.  However, I want to throttle the number of requests to the WS to say no more than 5 concurrent requests executing at any one time. All calls to the WS are made using `async/await`. I am using the TPL dataflow `BufferBlock` with a `BoundedCapacity` of 5.  Everything is working properly but what I am noticing is that the consumer, which awaits the WS call, blocks the queue until its finished resulting in all the requests in the bufferblock being performed serially.  Is it possible to have the consumer always processing 5 items off the queue at a time?  Or do I need to set up multiple consumers or start looking into action blocks?  So in a nutshell I want to seed the queue with 5 items.  As one item is processed a sixth will take its place and so on so I always have 5 concurrent requests going until there are no more items to process.

I used this as my guide: [Async Producer/Consumer Queue using Dataflow](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html)

Thanks for any help.  Below is a simplified version of the code

```
//set up
BufferBlock<CustomObject> queue = new BufferBlock<CustomObject>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 5 });
var producer = QueueValues(queue, values);
var consumer = ConsumeValues(queue);
await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer, queue.Completion);
counter = await consumer;

//producer
function QueueValues(BufferBlock<CustomObject> queue, IList<CustomObject> values)
{

    foreach (CustomObject value in values)
    {
        await queue.SendAsync(value);
    }
    queue.Complete();
}


//consumer
function ConsumeValues(BufferBlock<CustomObject> queue)
{
    while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        CustomObject value = await queue.ReceiveAsync();
            await CallWebServiceAsync(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of TPL Dataflow is rather strange. Normally, you'd move the consumption and processing *into the flow*. Append a `TransformBlock` to call the webservice. Delete `ConsumeValues`.

`ConsumeValues` executes sequentially which is fundamentally not what you want.

Instead of `BoundedCapacity` I think you rather want `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ActionBlock` with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` set to 5. You may also want to set a `BoundedCapacity` but that's for throttling the producer and not the consumer:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<CustomObject>(
    item => CallWebServiceAsync(item), 
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
        BoundedCapacity = 1000
    });

foreach (CustomObject value in values)
{
    await block.SendAsync(value);
}
block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```