# Concurrent parallel job processing with throttling using ActionBlock in TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am using the below code snippet to try and run jobs (selected by user from UI) non-blocking from main thread (asynchronously) and concurrently w.r.t each other, with some throttling set up to prevent too many jobs hogging all RAM. I used many sources such as Stephen Cleary's [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997326/tpl-dataflow-consumer-to-process-multiple-items-at-a-time) link on `ActionBlock` as well as [this](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2016/05/23/tpl-dataflow/) one from @i3arnon

```
public class ActionBlockJobsAsyncImpl {
    private ActionBlock<Job> qJobs;
    private Dictionary<Job, CancellationTokenSource> cTokSrcs;
    public ActionBlockJobsAsyncImpl () {
        qJobs = new ActionBlock<Job>(
               async a_job => await RunJobAsync(a_job),
               new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
               {
                   BoundedCapacity = boundedCapacity,
                   MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism,
               });
        cTokSrcs = new Dictionary<Job, CancellationTokenSource>();
    }

    private async Task<bool> RunJobAsync(Job a_job) {
        JobArgs args = JobAPI.GetJobArgs(a_job);
        bool ok = await JobAPI.RunJobAsync(args, cTokSrcs[a_job].Token);

        return ok;
    }

    private async Task Produce(IEnumerable<Job> jobs) {
        foreach (var job in jobs)
        {
            await qJobs.SendAsync(job);
        }
        //qJobs.Complete();
    }

    public override async Task SubmitJobs(IEnumerable<Job> jobs) {
        //-Establish new cancellation token and task status
        foreach (var job in jobs) {
            cTokSrcs[job] = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        // Start the producer.
        var producer = Produce(jobs);

        // Wait for everything to complete.
        await Task.WhenAll(producer);
    }
}
```

The reason I commented out the `qJobs.Complete()` method call was because the user should be able to submit jobs continuously from the UI (same ones or different ones), and I learnt from implementing and testing in my first pass using `BufferBlock` that I shouldn't have that `Complete()` call if I wanted such a continuous producer/consumer queue. But `BufferBlock` as I learnt doesn't support running concurrent jobs; hence this is my second pass with `ActionBlock` instead.

In the above code using `ActionBlock`, when the user selects jobs and clicks to run from UI, this calls the `SubmitJobs` method. The `int` parameters `boundedCapacity=8` and `maxDegreeOfParallelism=DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded` But the code as is, currently does nothing (i.e., it doesn't run any job) - my analogous `BufferBlock`  implementation on the other hand, used to at least run the jobs asynchronously, albeit sequentially w.r.t each other. Here, it never runs any of the jobs and I don't see any error messages either. Appreciate any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and perhaps some useful ideas on how to fix the problem. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Use the debugger to see if RunJobAsync is entered. A simpler design would be to just use `SemaphoreSlim` to throttle. No need to dataflow. Also note, that when SubmitJobs completes not all jobs will have completed because SendAsync does not wait for processing. Maybe this effect caused you to conclude that the jobs did not run at all when in reality they were just about to start.

Comment: @usr: yes, it does enter. The same behavior is also seen when I uncommented the qJobs.Complete() and added the await qjobs.Completion like in the link provided. I enabled all exceptions and saw that it throws System.InvalidOperationException something about cross thread access of an object not being legal. I am not sure how this is different from the example of i3arnon.

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo: Can you post a complete example that others can copy into VS and execute?

Comment: @usr: maybe so, but I doubt it. If it works for BufferBlock with the same code pretty much, and not for ActionBlock, and it could be very well be a bug, but it has to do with dataflow.

Comment: @Stephen, thanks, let me try to come up with something like that.

Comment: `something about cross thread access of an object not being legal` maybe you should investigate that... don't you think?? You have a very concrete lead here. What is your interpretation of that exception?

Comment: @usr: yes indeed, but it should be related to usage w.r.t ActionBlock, right??? What is it about the usage that is off? Otherwise the same thing works no issues repeatedly and robustly for BufferBlock.

Comment: Maybe increased parallelism triggers a bug. Also, I don't know what precisely the old code did. Many possible explanations, all unlikely but it's one of them.

Comment: @usr: Thanks, I did a quick test by setting maxDegreeOfParallelism=1 and still same behavior. If you have any other ideas on how to investigate further, or see any issue with the usage, please let me know..Thanks.

Comment: You should investigate the exception. My previous comment was deleted, unclear why. The exception is the primary lead here. It tells you where what crashed. My impression is that you are assuming the dataflow causes the error and are not even looking at the exception. Also, you should post it here so that we can see it.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried with maxDegreeOfParallelism=1, I got no exception of any kind, but still no result.. and nothing happens. I am unable to figure out why it doesn't even work for this case. BufferBlock works correctly all the time.